# How to handle the decimal values of my dropdown list without rounding or trimming zeros

Tags: javascript, jquery, decimal, rounding

I have a drop down list with decimal values. (formatted as string)

```
<select id="SizeBox">
   <option id="size_5" value="14.00">14</option>
   <option id="size_6" value="16.00">16</option>
   <option id="size_7" value="18.00">18</option>
   <option id="size_8" value="20.00">20</option>
   <option id="size_9" value="24.00">24</option>
   <option id="size_10" value="28.00">28</option>
   <option id="size_11" selected="selected" value="28.35">28,35</option>
   <option id="size_12" value="36.00">36</option>
</select>
```

I always take the selected value and save it in a variable:

```
var backupSize = "28.35";
```

When the user selected another size and wants to undo his changes, I provide a reset button that should select the backupSize value again.

```
SelectSize(parseFloat(backupSize).toFixed(2));

function SelectSize(size) {
   $('#SizeBox').val(size);
}
```

The problem is that using this toFixed method removes my decimal precision and pass the value 28.00 to the SelectSize function. Offcourse, there is no option in my list with this value so the reset function fails.

If i use the SelectSize function without the toFixed(2) part, then values like "20.00" will be passed as "20" and the SelectSize function will also fail to reset the size in the dropdown box.

I've searched for function that handle these decimal numbers just like strings but without success so far. How can i solve this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is there a reason you're converting from a string to a float whilst dealing with the dropdown?  If you leave it as a string then your problem is gone. `SelectSize(backupSize);`

Comment: What's the difference between `28.00` and `28`? As strings they're different, but as decimal numbers, they're exactly the same. Why do you care about the trailing zeroes (which mean nothing, really)?

Comment: dropdownlist is created on codebehind. The value i save in the backup variable is formatted like this "28,35" while the value of the option item is "28.35" and also "20" instead of "20.00". I'll try to see if i can fix this on code behind. I maybe was to early with my question here..

Comment: I have updated my answer below, it should solve the issue, if I understood it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something that will work with justabout any value:
working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4DSNS/2/

```
var backupSize = 20
var backupSize = 28.35
var backupSize = "28.35"
var backupSize = "20.00"
var backupSize = "20"
var backupSize = "28.35"
var backupSize = "28,35"
function SelectSize(size) {
   size = size.toString().replace(',','.');
   parseFloat(size).toFixed(2);
   $('#SizeBox').val(size);
}

SelectSize(backupSize);
```

Comment: Hehe, yes that's what i needed. I also just found out that toFixed will remove the decimals behind the "," character. toFixed only works for format like 5.45 (using a point) sometimes the simple replace function is the best format tool :)

Answer (score 0):

modify your selectSize function like this:

```
SelectSize(backupSize);

function SelectSize(size) {
    $("#sizebox option").attr("selected","");
    $("#sizebox option[value='"+size+"']").attr("selected","selected");
}
```

Comment: This would not make any difference cause the size parameter would be "6" while the option in the list has a value "6.00"

Comment: size parameter would be passed as string because I didn't use any parseFloat and I used it inside the element query as is. You didn't try it, did you?

Comment: No I did not try. You're code is not wrong, it will work if i can pass the correct value. In my situation, i have the following backup sizes: 5 6 7 8 10 12 16 20 24,35 but my dropdownlist has the values: 5.00 5.00 7.00 8.00 10.00 12.00 16.00 20.00 24.35  To resolve the last value I need size = Size.toString().replace(',','.'); and to make sure all numbers have the decimal precision of 2 numbers i need: parseFloat(size).toFixed(2);
adding these two lines two your code would also work but i prefer the shorter version: $('#SizeBox').val(size); But still, thanks for helping :)

Comment: you wrote in your question `var backupSize = "28.35";` and I prepared the code for this definition. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Hiya tdk plz see this **working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/B3Uwj/1/

Please let me know if I missed something, this is working fine as supposed to. i.e.

It works when 20.00 is passed, It does not fail quote:

> If i use the SelectSize function without the toFixed(2) part, then
>   values like "20.00" will be passed as "20" and the SelectSize function
>   will also fail to reset the size in the dropdown box.

**Jquery code**

```
var backupSize = "20.00";

SelectSize(parseFloat(backupSize).toFixed(2));

function SelectSize(size) {
    alert("Size is (Preserving the .00 ==> " + size);
   $('#SizeBox').val(size);
} 

// mini jQuery plugin that formats to two decimal places
    (function($) {
        $.fn.currencyFormat = function() {
            this.each( function( i ) {
                $(this).change( function( e ){
                    if( isNaN( parseFloat( this.value ) ) ) return;
                    this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
                });
            });
            return this; //for chaining
        }
    })( jQuery );

    // apply the currencyFormat behaviour to elements with 'currency' as their class
    $( function() {
        $('.currency').currencyFormat();
    });​
```

Comment: Thanks for this code example, but it seems my only problem in my case was that i was using the "," character instead of "." for floating point separater.

Comment: @ThdK No worries :) Glad you found the answer B-) you can use `.replace` api of query but I reckon you already founf the answer. :)